# Retrieving the preferences from the xml file in Android

Tags: android, xml, settings

I am new to Android and I am trying to handle the settings according to the instructions in

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

I used the fragment based solution as the one directly in the activity was deprecated:

```
public class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // Load the preferences from an XML resource
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingFragment())
            .commit();
    }
}
```

The settings are correctly displayed in the app, yet when I try to retrieve their values with:

```
sharedPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Dashboard.dashboard);
startDayTime=sharedPref.getString(SettingsActivity.day_switch_start, "");
startNightTime=sharedPref.getString(SettingsActivity.night_switch_start, "");
```

it complaints that values day_switch_start and night_switch_start might not be resolved. In fact, when I explode the values recognized by SettingActivity, I get a long list of capitalized strings part of the standard settings, but not my own strings.
 Those were in fact just entered in the xml file and linked from the SettingFragment, so I doubt context Dashboard.dashboard I passed has any reference to it. Yet there are no instructions on how to pass the settings references to a specific context and moreover they say that the settings should be available from anywhere. I am stuck, any solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please check the reference you linked again, especially the [Reading Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs) section. When you set the preference key to, e.g., `day_switch_start` then you must use the same String when reading the preference, e.g.,

```
startDayTime=sharedPref.getString("day_switch_start", "");
```

You can also store the preference key to a constant like in the linked example:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    public static final String KEY_PREF_DAY_SWITCH_START = "day_switch_start";
    // ...
```

and then access it when reading the preference:

```
startDayTime=sharedPref.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_DAY_SWITCH_START, "");
```

Edit: I'm not sure what `Dashboard.dashboard` should represent but this should work:

```
sharedPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Comment: Yep, thanks. I tried your first solution and it compiles. Yet it crashes with a java.lang.NullPointerException at sharedPref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Dashboard.dashboard);
Surely Google handles its instructions quite creatively...

Comment: Please check my edit. Why are you using `Dashboard.dashboard`? Did you find this in the reference?

Comment: Yes, in fact I moved the call too early and that activity was not yet created. Actually, by moving it at the right place, it works. My problem was in fact also that my phone is on charge and the simulator strangely crashes while creating a service, so I had to comment that call out in order to test this. Given your kindness, have you got some cue about why the simulator is not able to start the service? Or how I  may I know more. Sorry, but I come from the iOS world where Apple tells things definitely in a different way and even crashes have more sense.

Comment: Please ask a new question about the crash and include the relevant logcat output there.